# How to create array of objects?

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

How to create an Array of objects like the below C++ example?

What's the Ruby way of doing `Print print[1000];`?

The below code is C++. I'm just wondering if Ruby has an option to instantiate 1000 unique objects of a class:

```
class Print
{

public:
    Print()
    {
        static int count = 0;
        cout<<"h"<<++count<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    Print print[1000];
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that not `C++`? Interesting if its not

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I came through the program as a solution for printing 1000 chars without loop or recursion.

Comment: I suppose `count` is a global variable and the output looks like: "h0 h1 h2 h3 "... ?

Comment: @ThomasW yes thats how its supposed to be

Comment: @Shiva that is `C++`, not `Ruby`. You are looking at the wrong code if its `Ruby` you want to work with

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Ofcourse its c++, I'm just wondering whats the ruby way to instantiate 1000 objects of a class

Comment: Is it the output you want? Or the 1000 instances?

Comment: Is the output important at all? Or just the instances?

Comment: @downvoter care to explain ?

Comment: This is a silly question. What do you mean "no loop or recursion"  What do you think the C++ `Print print[1000]` does?  It loops, invoking the constructor 1000 times.  So does Ruby `Array.new(1000)` as does as `(0..999).to_a`.  But none of them notationally say "loop", the loop is implied, but certainly happens under the covers.

Comment: "the loop is implied, but certainly happens under the covers" I agree with you, but this is not a silly question ,answers given by vgoff and Steve Wilhelm made me to think I still have a tons of things to learn in ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get 1000 copies of a string instantiated, we can do this:

```
collection_of_strings = Array.new(1000, String.new('h'))
print collection_of_strings
```

This is the same object stored in the array.  And then that array printed.

This form of Array.new with the block given will create an individually instantiated object, however many times you gave for the argument:

```
>> collection = Array.new(10) {String.new}   
=> ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

And the proof by checking `object_id`  of each object in the array.

```
>> collection.each {|e| puts e.object_id}    
85621980                                     
85621970                                     
85621960                                     
85621950                                     
85621940                                     
85621930                                     
85621920                                     
85621910                                     
85621900                                     
85621890                                     
=> ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but seems the `initialize` is called only once

Comment: Hmm... You are correct.  This form works with individually unique objects... (editted)

Comment: Thanks `Array.new(10) {String.new}` is what I am looking for

Answer (score 3):

Given that

> "I suppose count is a global variable and the output looks like: "h0 h1 h2 h3 "

The following should work (see `Array#new` block for details [1]). It doesn't require an external variable, the block is passed the array's index:

```
Array.new(1000) {|count| "h#{count}"}
```

to put them all in one string, try:

```
Array.new(1000) {|count| "h#{count}"}.join(' ')
```

[1] http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-c-new

Answer (score 0):

To get that output with Ruby you can just do: `puts (0..999).to_a`.

Or, if you want the 'h's you can do: `(0..999).each {|n| puts "h#{n}"}`

Comment: But the solution should not have loop or recusrion

Comment: @shiva: Why no loops or recursion? Are you asking people to do your homework for you?

Comment: No i think you are misunderstanding my question, I just wondering how to port the exact solution in ruby

Comment: @muistooshort actually he can ask people to do this homework for him if the question is clear and precise :P

Comment: @Nobita: But it should be stated that it is homework and they should have a basic understanding of what they're doing (doubly so if it is homework).

Comment: Don't use `each` when you want `map`: `puts (0..999).map{|n| "h#{n}"}`

Comment: @dbenhur: Or prettier: `1000.times.map { ... }` :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to ThomasW's answer:

```
output = []
1000.times do |i| { output << "h#{i}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is! In translating your C++ to Ruby, this is what I come up with:

```
#create dummy class
class Kraken
  # equivalent to your C++ static variable which I think
  # should be declared outside the constructor
  @@count = 0

  # increment the count class variable on every 
  def initialize
    @@count = @@count + 1
  end
end

# Release the Kraken!
kraken = Array.new(1000) { Kraken.new }
```

Comment: Thanks @Yasky But the sole purpose of the C++ program is to print without loop or recusrion.So in you soln `Array.new(1000){Kraken.new}` should do fine

Comment: @shiva: `Array.new(1000){Kraken.new}` contains an implicit loop (specifically, in MRI, `for (i=0; i<len; i++) { rb_ary_store(ary, i, rb_yield(LONG2NUM(i))); ARY_SET_LEN(ary, i + 1); }`). There is no way to do this in Ruby (or any other language) without a loop of some sort, just like the C++ code will invoke the constructor 1000 times when compiled to machine code.