# Ruby: Why are all coordinates getting updated in an array of arrays?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to change a specific coordinate, but an array is getting all updated.

The goal is to change the `fixed` attribute to a single coordinate.

```rb
class Case
  attr_accessor :fixed

  def initialize
    self.fixed = false
  end

  def fixed?
    !!fixed
  end
end

def display(arr)
  5.times do |x|
    5.times do |y|
      print arr[x][y].fixed?
      print ' '
    end

    puts
  end
end

# Defining array
arr = Array.new(5){ Array.new(5, Case.new) }

# Displaying the arrays
display(arr)

# Changing value of a single coord
arr[2][3].fixed = true

# Displaying the arrays
display(arr)
```

Here is the result for the first display call

```rb
false false false false false 
false false false false false 
false false false false false 
false false false false false 
false false false false false
```

And second display

```rb
false false false false false 
false false false false false 
true true true true true 
false false false false false 
false false false false false
```

The expected result is:

```rb
false false false false false 
false false false false false 
false false false true false 
false false false false false 
false false false false false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are placing the same instance in the row multiple times.  To make each item in the array a new object change your array definition to the following:

```
arr = Array.new(5){ Array.new(5) {Case.new}   }
```

See this question for more info: [How to create array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184717/how-to-create-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the way you create the array:

```
arr = Array.new(5){ Array.new(5, Case.new) }
```

`arr` is an array of 5 arrays (`Array.new(5) {...}`), each of them containing 5 references to the same instance of the `Case` class (`Array.new(5, Case.new)`).

There inner arrays and the outer arrays are created in different ways.

#### The outer array

```
Array.new(5){ ... }
```

This code fragment creates an array of 5 elements using a block to initialize each element. The block is executed 5 times (once for each array element). The block creates and returns a new array each time (the inner arrays).

#### The inner arrays

```
Array.new(5, Case.new)
```

This code fragment creates an array of 5 elements and initialize each of them with the same value. The value, returned by calling `Case.new` once, before `Array.new()` is an object an Ruby puts 5 references to it into the array returned by `Array.new()`.

### The solution

I hope it is clear now how to create an array of 5 different arrays that contain 5 different values. One way is to create the inner arrays the same way as the outer array: by calling `Array.new()` with one argument (the number of elements) and a block to be executed to initialize each element:

```
arr = Array.new(5){ Array.new(5) { Case.new } }
```

---

Read about [`Array.new()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-c-new) in the Ruby documentation.